# getText() method returns empty string

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the HTML of the web page:

```
<td class=" gridCell wrapText " style="height:27px;" headers="a15" data-post="" title="">
<div class="oflowDivM ">
<span>
<script src="webwb/pzpega_control_text_12877380907.js!!.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<span class="leftJustifyStyle" data-ctl="Text">30,980,030.0000</span>
</span>
</div>
```

My intention is to extract the value 30,980,030.0000
I am using the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/span/span")).getText();
```

However, the `getText()` returns an empty string. The `xpath` is correct as I do not get `NoSuchElementException`. Could you please help in identifying my mistake here?

Comment: why not try by class name only...driver.findElement(By.classname("leftJustifyStyle")).getText();

Comment: I tried that as well. But it results in an empty string. The xpath works fine but getText() returns an empty string

Comment: can you share the link to html page

Comment: Sorry, the website opens only in my client network

Comment: please add few more lines of html code

Comment: is this content dynamically generated by some JS then please add some wait before looking for the text

Comment: Could be that your xpath finds more than 1 node. And it tries to get text of the first found, which is not the node you are expecting. You can check this in developer tools of your browser.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/span/span")).getAttribute("outerHTML"));`. Is it printing the element you are expecting? If it does, put a breakpoint on that line, let the script run until it breaks, and then run the line... does it work now? If so, you probably need a wait in there.

Comment: Apart from your question, what is the reason for a script tag in a span loading a javascript file?

Comment: 1. When you try this xpath, //td/div/span/span, on the browser console/firepath how many matching nodes do you get? 2. If you get only 1 matching node and the highlighted element is correct, If you're using firepath, paste //td/div/span/span//text() and see what it returns. Alternatively, if you're using any of the consoles use this: $x("//td/div/span/span//text()") and see what it returns. 3. If the number of matching nodes returned is greater than 1, the first occurrence will be considered and that may not have any text indicating that you need to fix your xpath to point to the right element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please try below and see if value is printed or not:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/span/span")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

If it still happens, can you try to have few seconds of wait and then try yo find element and get the text.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/span/span")).getAttribute("innerText"); returns a NullPointerException. Adding wait also results in an empty string being returned.

Comment: can you try to store this element into a variable of WebElement type and then check if it is printing any of its defined attribute or not.

Comment: Also, check if element is visible or not using element.isDisplayed(); print this value and see what value it prints

Answer (score 5):

I probably think your element is hidden so getText() returns blank. The comment from @JeffC should fix your problem. Otherwise, try code below:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
string text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td > div span.leftJustifyStyle")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

or find only span which contains string that is longer than 2 characters

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
string text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/span/span[string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 2]")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String amount = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*td[@class='gridCell wrapText']//div[@class='oflowDivM']//span//span[@class='leftJustifyStyle']")).getText();
```

This should work - just make sure class names are correct as in HTML...

Comment: Empty string here as well :(

Comment: edited my answer - try again...also please cross check the class names used here with actual class names in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

String details = "";

Thread.sleep(3000);

details = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div//span")).getAttribute("value");

Comment: This results in NullPointerException as there is no attribute "value" as seen from the html

Comment: "30,980,030.0000" is this the text you actually needed

Comment: can you please get me the page,please attach link

Comment: try this: 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*div[@class='oflowDivM']//span//span)).getText();

or 

 driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*div[@class='oflowDivM']//span//span)).getAttribute("value");

Comment: unfortunately the website opens only in client network. The xpath did not work. I suspect that there is something that is stopping getText() from reading the value as the element is getting identified by all the xpaths tried, however the getText() returns empty string

Comment: `getAttribu‌​te("value")` will work only for input type elements. For span you can try `getAttribu‌​te("textContent")`;

Answer (score 0):

From what I found out `getText()` sometimes returns empty string (if the element is hidden for example. I'm not sure if is or not the only case and neither about the cause).

Anyway what worked for me was `getAttribute("textContent")`.

So how about something like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/span/span")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

?